# how to log the body of a stream in camel using a Tracer?

Tags: java, apache-camel

I know how to get Apache Camel (2.10.3) to log the body of a stream (soap message) using the Log component. However, I want to use the Tracer instead of Log.

The [docs](http://camel.apache.org/tracer.html) say to enable the LOG_DEBUG_BODY_STREAMS property, I did that but that doesn't seem to make a difference:

```
    <bean id="camelTracer" class="org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.Tracer">
    <property name="traceOutExchanges" value="true"/>
    <property name="traceExceptions" value="true"/>
    <property name="logStackTrace" value="true"/>
    <property name="traceInterceptors" value="true"/>
    <property name="logLevel" value="TRACE"/>
    <property name="logName" value="xxx.cameltracer"/>
</bean>     

<bean id="traceFormatter" class="org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.DefaultTraceFormatter">
    <property name="showBody" value="true"/>
    <property name="showOutBody" value="true"/>
    <property name="showBodyType" value="false"/>
    <property name="showBreadCrumb" value="true"/>
    <property name="showHeaders" value="false"/>
</bean> 

<camelContext id="camelContext" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" streamCache="true" trace="true">
    <properties>
       <property key="CamelLogDebugBodyStreams" value="true"/>
    </properties>
    ...
```

Anything else I need to configure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a type-o in your property, it should be:

```
<camelContext id="camelContext" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" streamCache="true" trace="true">
    <properties>
       <property key="CamelLogDebugStreams" value="true"/>
    </properties>
```

Comment: Doh, must have copied it from a wrong source. Here, have some easy rep!

Comment: The easiest errors are sometimes the ones that are the hardest to find. Weird that the constant is different in text from the java constant as well. Logically, it should be as you typed it.

Comment: "Doh, must have copied it from a wrong source": That would be the official [Camel documentation](http://camel.apache.org/how-do-i-enable-streams-when-debug-logging-messages-in-camel.html)!  `<camelContext>
    <properties>
        <property key="CamelLogDebugBodyStreams" value="true"/>
   </properties>
</camelContext>`